# Node tls.TLSSocket not initiating TLS handshake?

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to implement a client for a own chat project in Node
but when upgrading the socket to TLS on the client node appears not to start the TLSHandshake

my code looks like this

```js
const net = require("net")
const rl = require("readline")
const tls = require("tls")

var socket = new net.Socket()
  socket.connect(8099, "localhost")
  var i = rl.createInterface(socket, socket)
  i.on("line", (line) => {
    if (line.startsWith("SERVER::VERSION")) {
      socket.write("CLIENT::VERSION::0.3::TLS\n")
      i.close()
    }
  })
  i.on("close", () => {
    tls_sock = new tls.TLSSocket(socket, {isServer: false})
  })
```

the when opening a socket with ncat, i do not see a handshake
output:

```
SERVER::VERSION::0.3::TLS
CLIENT::VERSION::0.3::TLS
```

the above line was typed / sent by me

am i missing something trivial here ?

*edit*
even when using this snipped, the handshake does not get initiated

```
socket = new net.Socket()
socket.connect(8099, "localhost")
socket.on("connect", (line) => {
  tls_sock = new tls.TLSSocket(socket, {isServer: false})
})
```

Comment: Perhaps you need to write something with `tls_sock` or explicitly call `tls.connect()` to create your TLSSocket object.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was not use use TLSSocket like described in whatever tutorial i found but to call tls.connect({socket:socket})